# The [default] keyword doesn't work for C# generic type return value?

Tags: c#, generics, reference, null, default

I'm converting some old C# code to use C# 8, and have encountered this problem:

```
class MyList<T> : IMyEnumberable<T>
{
    public T GetDefault()
    {
        return default;// a default expression introduces a null value when 'T' is a non-nullable reference type
    }
}
```

It failed to compile and says

> a default expression introduces a null value when 'T' is a non-nullable reference type

I'm not sure what is the problem here - any explanations?

Comment: Have a look at this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/), _The issue with T?_ part

Comment: strange, i think i'm using it like that in a project... have you tried `default(T)` wich should not be necessary anymore due to target typed interference. but maybe i'm just on preview with that project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that someone could do:

```
var list = new MyList<string>();
string d = list.GetDefault();
```

Because they created a `MyList<string>`, then `T` is `string`, (i.e. a non-nullable string). Therefore because `GetDefault()` returns a `T`, this should mean that it returns a non-nullable string.

However if they call `GetDefault()`, that will return `default(string)`, which is `null`. They'll get `null` when they weren't expecting one!

---

You can't prevent someone from creating a `MyList<string>`: there's no syntax to say "`T` must *only* be a nullable type, and must not be a non-nullable type".

If you constrain `T` to be a `struct` or `class`, you can write:

```
class MyList<T> : IMyEnumberable<T> where T : struct // or : class
{
    public T? GetDefault()
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a `[MaybeNull]` to the return type of `GetDefault()` to say that, even though it returns `T` (and `T` may be non-nullable), this method might actually return `null`.

(Note that currently this only affects *callers* of `GetDefault()`, and not the actual body, so you'll still need the null-suppressing operator `!`. It looks like this will change soon):

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

class MyList<T> : IMyEnumberable<T>
{
    [return: MaybeNull]
    public T GetDefault()
    {
        return default!;
    }
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEA3GUCWAZgJ4A+AAgEwCMAsAFDkAMABOdQHQAi+AhgOYA7CAGcM+MCI4BhCABMYAQUG8ANsRH4RAbgYMAxIICuq1b2CqYLGCosw9jAMxtKLaQwDeDFj5/ln5CgsALIAFACU3r4sXvTR8di8UCyqWhgsALwsgjAA7iHEADJpADzsTAB8Ebpx8b7lLLAiJulZqWIcAOIwGFwwhLwt1VG+AL4M4/QM/iz4ghh4A2BWAJLBxACixgC2wHjmliUAKhWeIyxHLN29/YOqGMP0k9Ou68VixxUsICxrmzt7KAHGCfM61HwAbXIAHYfsFeMQ9gA5EyqAC65xml2ufQGQ0i4Ji52iMJYCjx9wAhDVopNRkA===).

Answer (score 1):

You don't put any constraint to your generic T, so basically T can be anything. That's why you got default null.

```
var test = new MyList<SomeClass>().GetDefault(); // This gives you null
var test2 = new MyList<int>().GetDefault(); // This gives you 0
```

If you want to force T must be non-nullable, use this.

```
class MyList<T> where T : struct
```